# Error: spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for login()

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying on unit test for login using karma and jasmine. I got the following error when I test my code using karma start unit-tests.conf.js.

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) LoginController doLoginAction should call login method on UserService FAILED

Error: spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for login()

Here I am including my login.controller.tests.js page.

```
describe('LoginController', function() {

    var scope, controller, userServiceMock, stateMock;

    beforeEach(module('user.controllers'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('LoginController',{
            $scope: scope,
            $state: stateMock,
            UserService: userServiceMock
        });
    }));

    beforeEach(function() {
        scope.doLoginAction = jasmine.createSpy('doLoginAction')
    });

    describe('doLoginAction',function(){
        it('should call odLoginAction method on LoginController', function(){
            scope.doLoginAction();
        });

        it('should call login method on UserService', function(){            
            spyOn(userServiceMock,'login');
            expect(userServiceMock.login).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
                username:'riju@gmail.com',
                password:'riju'
            });                
        });
    });        
});
```

doLoginAction function in my controller page.

```
$scope.doLoginAction = function () {
    UserService.login($scope.creds.username, $scope.creds.password)
        .then(function (_response) {

            alert("login success " + _response.attributes.username);

            // transition to next state
            $state.go('tab.list');

        }, function (_error) {
            alert("error logging in " + _error.message);
        })
};
```

What I am doing wrong, please help me.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Must inject the `userServiceMock` service, refer below code.

```
   beforeEach(module('user.controllers'));
   beforeEach(module('YOUR SERVICE MODULE'));

   beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, userServiceMock) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('LoginController',{
            '$scope' : scope,
            '$state' : stateMock,
            'UserService' : userServiceMock
        });
    }));
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. When I try this code, I got the following error

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) LoginController doLoginAction should call odLoginAction method on LoginController FAILED
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: userServiceMockProvider <- userServiceMock
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/unpr?p0=userServiceMockProvider%20%3C-%20userServiceMock

Comment: did you add your UserService file to `karma.conf.js`, then only you can able to inject the `UserService`. And then use `beforeEach(module('your service module'));`

Comment: my service module is 'user.services'. After adding the user.service module the error remains the same. thanks..

Comment: Lets try like `'$scope' : scope, '$state' : stateMock, 'UserService' : userServiceMock` in the $controller.

Comment: Now I got this error:

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) LoginController doLoginAction should call odLoginAction method on LoginController FAILED
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: userServiceMockProvider <- userServiceMock
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/unpr?p0=userServiceMockProvider%20%3C-%20userServiceMock.

thanks